# Alias Test in c++?

Tags: c++

My professor was going through slides and went across "alias test," saying we should all know what this is, so he will not explain it.

I have never heard of this before, and he refused to explain it, saying I should know what it is by now.

The only thing my classmates and I can find in the course materials is he went over a code snippet in class and said, "The alias test here is used to make sure that the `operator=` is not used on itself."

Can anyone help to provide some insight on what this is?

Comment: That is not a standard term in C++ programming.  Maybe he meant "type alias", which can be defined using the keyword `typedef` or `using`.  Surely you have more information about this than just 2 words in a slide.

Comment: what context was it in?  Did they perhaps mean you will have a test on aliases?

Comment: @DavidGrayson We have an assignment and he asks the question: "What is an alias test? Describe its purpose." Though, none of us know what this means. The only thing we have to go off of is he went over a code snippet in class and said, "The alias test here ix used to make sure that the operator= is not used on itself."

Comment: Nope, me neither; no idea what **alias test** is supposed to convey.  Unless it is a meta-test to see if anyone has the guts to stand-up and ask "What does alias test mean?"

Comment: @NathanOliver We have an assignment and he asks the question: "What is an alias test? Describe its purpose." Though, none of us know what this means. The only thing we have to go off of is he went over a code snippet in class and said, "The alias test here ix used to make sure that the operator= is not used on itself."

Comment: Oh [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_(computing)) in computer programming means two different variables that point to the same thing.  If you are writing your own operator= on your class, you might want to check to make sure the user did try to assign an object to itself (e.g. `a = a;`), since the code in your assignment operator might crash depending on what exactly you are doing.  So you might want to *test* for *aliasing* in your assignment operator.

Comment: That sounds like a check against self-assignment.  I've not heard that called **alias test** before (but I've not been everywhere).  There are better strategies for protecting against self-assignment without having an "alias test", which penalizes the most travelled code path in favor of the pathological case.

Comment: Your little description a few comments up sound a lot like what we usually call "self assignment."

Comment: @DavidGrayson That makes a lot more sense. Thank you so much for you help!

Comment: @Eljay Thank you so much for your comment, I appreciate you trying to help. After doing some research based off what you said, I believe you are completely right!

Comment: The "alias test" sounds like a description your professor, or some people s/he works with, just made up. Your description suggests it is about a self-assignment test when implementing a class' `operator=()`,  such as `SomeClass &SomeClass::operator=(const SomeClass &rhs) {if (this != &rhs) { do_assignment(); } return *this;}`. This approach has limitations (e.g. it doesn't work if `SomeClass` has a unary `operator&()`, it is often unsafe - leaves an object in unexpected/invalid state - if an exception is thrown) and other approaches (e.g. copy and swap) are often considered preferable.

Answer (score 3):

[Aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_(computing)) in computer programming means two different variables that point to the same thing.  If you are writing your own `operator=` in your class, you might want to check to make sure the caller did not try to assign an object to itself (e.g. `a = a;`), since the code in your assignment operator might crash depending on what exactly you are doing.  So you might want to *test* for *aliasing* in your assignment operator, and the little bit of code that does that could be called an *alias test*.

Comment: However, I do not think that *alias test* is a standard term in C++ programming.

Comment: I feel like we should throw the copy swap idiom at this paleontology professor.